# Why call method of window object explicitly, performance will be lower than inexplicitly

Tags: javascript, web

In web environment think this code:

```
window.alert('foo'); //code1
alert('foo');        //code2
```

Why `code2` is higher than `code1` in performance? Why does this happened?

Comment: by higher in performance you mean slower/better ?

Comment: how the heck can you measure the difference!? it's not like you can benchmark `alert`!!!

Answer (score 2):

First, remember that many globals (including all of the traditional predefined globals) are properties of the *global object*, and that on browsers that global object is the window object. `window` isn't special, it's just a predefined global that refers to the global object. `alert` is also a predefined global.

`window.alert(...)` is slower than `alert(...)` because in `window.alert(...)` the JavaScript engine first has to:

1. Go look up the identifier `window`, which it ultimately finds as a property of the global object, then
2. Look up `alert` in that object's properties, then
3. Call the function it found

In `alert(...)`, it only has to:

1. Go look up the identifier `alert`, which it ultimately finds as a property of the global object, then
2. Call the function it found

So instead of looking for two things, it only has to look for one.

Less work = faster performance.

---

Having said that, two observations:

1. The speed with which you show an `alert` is...not usually important. :-) `alert` does, after all, seize up the JavaScript engine until the user dismisses it.
2. Even with something that doesn't seize up the JavaScript engine, the difference between `window.xyz(...)` and `xyz(...)` will be **trivially** small in most cases. Typically you see `window.xyz(...)` for *other* reasons (such as some other `xyz` being in scope when you want to access the global one). (I'm not saying they're *good* reasons; typically you can avoid that, and of course one tries to avoid globals wherever possible anyway...)
3. If performance calling a global function matters (by definition, this means you're calling it a ***lot***), you probably don't want to use the global reference to it anyway; grab a local reference to it in your inner scope (`var f = theGlobalFunction;`) and then use `f();` to call it repeatedly. This avoids both lexical environment traversal and lookup on the global object. And again: Only matters in **very** rare cases; don't do it until/unless you've identified an observable performance problem and narrowed it down to the global function call. :-)

The time for that first lookup (the global) depends on how deeply nested the code is (and thus how many lexical environment objects need searching before the global one is reached) and how many properties the global object has. The second part, looking up the property, is only dependent on the second one. A truly hideously massive mass of globals (such as is created if you use `id`s on lots of elements, since those get added as automatic globals) can conceivably slow down global lookup time.

Comment: Do you think that double search will be so much slower that it will be visible?

Comment: @Vitalii: Almost never, no.